# arcpy - how to run geoprocessing python script on SDE

Tags: python, geoprocessing, enterprise-geodatabase, ms-access

I was testing my script on a .gdb on my local drive and I got it to work. The actual geodatabase I would like to run the script on is an SDE. I tried changing my filepath from the .gdb to the .sde and it failed. Can someone help me figure out how to configure my script so that it will work on the SDE?

```
#import system module 
import arcpy, os

#define filepath
filepath = r"C:\Users\kkaszas\AppData\Roaming\ESRI\Desktop10.0\ArcCatalog\SANGeodatabase.sde"

arcpy.env.workspace = filepath

#enable overwrite 
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

fcList = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()
fieldName1 = "Author"
fieldName2 = "LastUpdated"
expression1 = "\"John Doe\""
expression2 = 20121011

for fc in fcList:

    arcpy.AddField_management(fc,fieldName1, "TEXT")
    arcpy.AddField_management(fc,fieldName2, "LONG")
    print "fields added to " + fc


    arcpy.CalculateField_management(fc, fieldName1, expression1, "PYTHON")
    arcpy.CalculateField_management(fc, fieldName2, expression2,"PYTHON")
    print "Fields have been calculated for " + fc
```

Comment: Can you post the error message you're getting?

Comment: I am not getting an error, when I run the scrip the shell returns two blank lines.

Comment: Ohhh, so it sounds like its "completing" the script. Try putting some AddMessages in to print the "fc" or the "fclist". The ListFeatureClass function should work against the SDE workspace...

Comment: Also, what database backend is your SDE running on?

Comment: Its running on a SQL Express database.

Comment: After running the script, I checked the targeted feature classes from the SDE in ArcMap, the new fields have not been appended.

Comment: Are you accessing the sde connection as the DBO? And what filesize is the db?

Comment: Yes, I have DBO and admin permission. The db filesize is 605 MB.

Answer (score 2):

Set your `arcpy.env.workspace` to `"Database Connections\\\nameofdatabase.sde\\\"` or

```
arcpy.env.workspace = "Database Connections\\\nameofdatabase.sde\\\"
```

Hope that helps.